# How is IP reservation in DD-WRT different from that of D-Link?

Tags: wireless-router, dd-wrt

I've decided to make the switch from stock D-Link FW to DD-WRT. The router is a DIR-825, revision B1. I flashed it successfully with DD-WRT. It didn't connect me to the Internet at first, the "globe" LED light was orange. I didn't have the uplink cable connected to the router at the time I flashed it, so I had to connect it, and then reboot the router and then wait for a few minutes before it discovered my Internet connection. So far so good and I'm very happy with it.

But I am having one concern. How do I make IP reservations and forward ports? I have looked around the interface to get a feel for it and see what is what. But I'm not so sure how I'm supposed to make IP reservations.

In D-Link interface, I would fill out a "reservations list" where I type in the IP I wish to use for each of my clients, their corresponding MAC addresses and computer name. Then in Port Forwarding I would make a new rule and spcify the port number, TCP/UDP protocol and the IP address to forward to. How has this changed now that I have DD-WRT?

I have read on How-To Geek that this doesn't work the same way in the DD-WRT. The author talks in terms of "dhcp reservation" rather than "ip reservation". I don't understand this. Can someone explain?

Here's the article I'm referring to:

http://www.howtogeek.com/69612/how-to-set-up-static-dhcp-on-your-dd-wrt-router/

The article discusses "static dhcp". But I need a static ip, not dhcp. Is this the right tutorial for my situation? Yes, I know that the IP is assigned dynamically by the DHCP. But what's the big deal here with DD-WRT? The thing is that I don't want to be setting up static IP addresses on each of the computers, I still want the DHCP server enabled, but I just want to make sure that my IP addresses are reserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The How To Geek article you linked to is the correct article to cover what you want to do.

Static DHCP means that your computers will continue to receive IP addresses from the DHCP server (so you don't have to configure each PC manually), but that the leases will be static, meaning they will be the same each time a particular machine asks for an address.

Comment: So this corresponds to the 1440 minute lease time recommendation? So after 1440 minutes, or 24 hours, the router and the PC will negotiate for a new IP address but the PC will once again get that same IP address? If I understand this correctly it's something like this. When a PC or client side is set to use a specific IP address it is called "static IP", but when the router or the server side is set to only give out specific IP to a specific PC, this is called "static dhcp". Right? It's like having static IP but the other way around, where it is set in the router.

Comment: If this is true, then there really should not be any difference in setting static IP in DD-WRT compared the stock D-Link firmware. Making an "IP reservations list" in D-Link is the act of setting static DHCP. I mean there's no major advantage here really when comparing DD-WRT to D-Link. You still have to make a list of MAC and IP addresses and forward your ports accordingly.

Comment: Yes, IP reservation in the D-Link and static DHCP in DD-WRT are doing the exact same thing.  There isn't a single canonical name for this feature, so different firmwares name it slightly differently, but the functionality is the same.